# How do I store the file uploaded by user on my website onto azure using python script?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage, web-development-server

User uploads an excel file on my website. What python script should I write that uploads that file into Azure storage?

Comment: Hi, any progress now?

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Azure Storage Python sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) on your server side to upload files into Azure Storage.

```
from azure.storage.file import FileService, ContentSettings

def upload_files_to_azure(share, directory, path_of_file):
    file_service = FileService(account_name='<your account name>',
                               account_key='<your account key>')
    file_service.create_file_from_path(
        share,
        directory,
        '<file name>',
        path_of_file
    )
    return


upload_files_to_azure("<share name>", None, "<file path on your server>")
```

More details please refer to [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage).

Hope it helps you.